# Calculating 1 point per 10 pounds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a weight-loss app (similar to Weight Watchers), but I'm not sure how to add 1 "point" per 10 pounds of a person's weight.

Here's what I have so far: a user gets a certain number of points per day, and one point is added per ten pounds of weight. That is, a 100-pound user would have 10 points added to their daily points.

How would I do this calculation?

```
$(init);

var points = 0;//points start at 0

function init()
{
    $('#submit').click(calculatePoints);
    $('#statusBox').hide();
}

function calculatePoints()
{
    var female = $('input[id="fem"]:checked').val();//get value of gender radio buttons
    var male = $('input[id="male"]:checked').val();
    var age = $('#age').val();//value of age
    var weight = $('#weight').val();//value of weight
    var actHard = $('input[id="hard"]:checked').val();//value of lifestyle radio buttons
    var actMod = $('input[id="mod"]:checked').val();
    var actSed = $('input[id="sed"]:checked').val();

    if (female)
    {
        points=8;   
    }

    else
    {
        points=2;
    }

    if (age<=26)
    {
        points=4
    }

    else if(age<=37)
    {
        points=3;
    }

    else if(age<=47)
    {
        points=2;
    }

    else
    {
        points=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Be sure to use `points +=` and not `points =`. i.e. if you have a female (8pts) and they are <26 (4pts), your code will not add them together. `points+=1` is equivalent to `points = points + 1` btw

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to divide their weight by 10.

```
points += weight / 10;
```

Comment: And you should be able to use Math.round(weight / 10), Math.ceil(weight / 10) or Math.floor(weight / 10) if you want a whole number of points (rounded at .5, rounded up, or rounded down respectively).

Answer (score 0):

points += Math.round(weight / 10);
That should do it. And make sure the user typed their weight in pounds, or you'll have to convert it.